# I can't put data in mysql db using php oop

Tags: php, oop

i have a problem and i need some help.
Here's the problem i have 2 class files : User.class.php and UserManager.class.php and an other php page.
The php page contain this code:

```
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['pass'];
        try{
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 'user', '');

            $userManager = new UserManager($db);

            $user= new User();

            $user->setName($name);
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setPassword($password);

            $userManager->add($user);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            die('Error : ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
```

I have no exceptions no errors but in same time nothing happen on the database. Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: why it should appear in database? Is UserManager in add method do this?

Comment: Have you set PDO to throw exceptions (it doesn't by default)? Where is your code for your classes?

Comment: yes the UserManager in add method must insert data into the DB.

Comment: This is my add method of the UserManager:

Comment: public function add(User $user){
  $query = $this->_db->prepare('INSERT INTO user (name, email, password) VALUES (:name, :email, :password)');
  $query->bindValue(':nom', $user->name());
  $query->bindValue(':email', $user->email());
  $query->bindValue(':password',    $user->password());
  $query->execute();

 }